# calling jquery modal dialog from jquery modal dialog

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog, modal-dialog, nested

hey folks,
i got stuck where i have to call another jquery modal dialog from an existing jquery modal dialog i couldn't achieve that will any body get me out of this problem

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is it out of the question to hide the first dialog, and show the second? You can track these items in an array and when the second one is closed, you can either keep both dialogs closed, or re-open the first.

Answer (score 1):

If you read this post, it shows that you need to init them both with one as "autoshow" to false and then toggle the display when necessary. There is also another option at the bottom but it seems a little hacky imo. It's not difficult to create your own dialog controller as I have done here: http://desktop.udjamaflip.com

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/making-a-diolog-box-open-another-dialog-box-why-does-it-only-work-once